# Excel 2010 area chart drop off

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I'm trying to create an area chart that shows data over a year. All the data for each month always add up to 100%.

An image is probably worth 1000 words, so here we go:

[image: example]

---

I would like the area chart to drop off vertically instead of in a diagonal like that. There is no data (yet) for July to December (the values are `NA()`) as you can see in the second part of the screenshot.

On the 3rd part, it's the dialog box options that would probably be called in English "Hidden and empty cells settings" or something like that (sorry it's in French). As you can see, the options are all disabled, can't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a vertical drop the stacked area series must only contain cells with data. If they include empty cells (or NA values), the area will be plotted to drop off to zero.

You can either manually adjust the series formulas or use dynamic range names that automatically adjust to the data.

Using a data sample similar to yours, please see the following screenshot

A dynamic range with a formula is used for the first data series.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1,1,0,COUNT(Sheet1!$B:$B),1)
```

The other data series are offsets of the first. Build the chart with the dynamic series. Now the X axis will only include the months with values. You need to add another data series that includes all 12 months, but has zero or no values. This is the "AxisSpacer" Series in the screenshot. You can remove the AxisSpacer from the legend, of course.

[image]

Comment: Got it working, I need to edit the SERIES() function by clicking the serie in the chart, but it won't work if I edit it using the Excel data selection box. Thank you.

Comment: What if I don't have any data for January for a specific set? Can I have data only for February to July in the above example?

Comment: The solution suggested by @Sebastian below works for me if you want a blank January.

Answer (score 3):

Try filling in high negative values and adopt the scale of the y-axis accordingly to not plot these. This will create a steep drop!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get a chart without a dropoff on the right (showing blank spaces), by using a "Placeholder" row that has a value of 0 across all columns.

1. Select the area you want on your table (notice, do NOT include empty/null cells)
   [image: Selected Data]
2. Create the Area Chart, using that selection, and click Select Data to modify some values. Click Edit to update the Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels, highlight your column headers again and click OK so you see them listed in the right panel, then uncheck the "blank series" in the left panel. You need to keep Placeholder checked to show your empty columns to the right of your data.
   [image: Changing Headers]
3. Finally, select and delete the Placeholder label in the legend, so it's as if it isn't there.
   [image: Finished chart]

Comment: This is basically the same as Teylyn's answer (don't refer to empty cells).